# Best Postgres/DB format for storing an array of strings with a boolean attached to them in Django?

Tags: sql, arrays, django, database, postgresql

I'm storing an array of URL links in my Postgres database like this:

```
urls = ArrayField(
    models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
)
```

But I want to track if a URL has been visited or not, as a boolean. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Would another related table be better for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField` which can store data as JSON and is `PostgreSQL` specific field. So you can put in it dict with `url` and `visited` keys in it.

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

...

urls = JSONField(encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder, default=dict)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField